# Insert Lines after Multi-Line Regex Match

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression, xml

I've got an XML file I need to append to after a specific set of tags.  Basically the file structure looks like this:

```
<key>servers</key>
<dict>
... Server Details ...
</dict>
```

I would like to match on the lines:

```
<key>servers</key>
<dict>
```

and append a block of XML specifying a server connection immediately after `<dict>`.  I've got the new XML block in its own text file as it's quite long.

I've looked at `sed` and `awk` to do this but I've come up against a wall.  I've also seen examples of using `perl` to accomplish this but I'm not so familiar with Perl.  From what I understand though, `sed` and `awk` aren't great at multiline matching.

The reason I need to do multiline matching is because the `<dict>` tag is used frequently within the XML file and I need to append a block into the `<key>servers</key>` section, as opposed to replacing its entire contents.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like:

```
awk '{print}
     $0 == "<dict>" && previous == "<key>servers</key>" {
       system("cat other-file.xml")
     }
     {previous = $0}'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sed '/keys_line_1/,/keys_line_last/{/keys_line_last/{
h;s/unique_split_point.*//;r /path/to/insert/file
x;s/.*unique_split_point//;G
}}'
```

`sed` is not exactly forgiving when it comes to requiring adjustments to an hypothesis. Everything `sed` does is a direct result of the thing it has just done, and so a very minor error in detail can drastically alter results.

In this way, without a little bit of crazy and a whole lot of patience, `sed` script debugging can be a frustrating affair, but, given those qualities, the rewards can be significant. I *highly* recommend using the `l`ook command during the process as much as you might if you make the attempt.

```
sed ...;l;...complicated_script...;l;...
```

Actually, looking a second time at your question, and I think it is easier than I at first assumed. All you really need *(I think)* is to expand pattern space by one line in a *servers* match case. By default `sed` buffers only a line per cycle, but the commands `N`, `P`, and `D` provide direct control over this behavior.

In fact, I believe I misunderstood the question originally - I though you wanted to insert some text into a line, not into a block of lines.

So you just maybe need:

```
sed '\|<key>servers</key>|,/<dict>/N;P
/\n<dict>/!D;s/.*\n//;r /path/to/file'
```

That way all the lines but those in which you are interested - the range from your *server* through your *dict* match are elided from the edit buffer as soon as might be, and you only `r` out your target file following the first *dict* match which follows any sequence of your *server, and the only point at which *file* is ever appended to the out buffer directly follows your *dict* match if it is preceded by a `\n`ewline.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?

```
sed '\|<key>servers</key>|{n
\|<dict>| r other-file.xml
}' file.xml
```

Comment: That assumes the `<key>servers</key>\n<dict>` doesn't follow another `<key>servers</key>` line.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be a little more specific on the result you expect ?
I'd use python3 and a

```
PATH = '/My/Path/'

FILE = 'MyFile.xml'

for i, line in enumerate(open(PATH+FILE, 'r')):

... #
```

since it's easy to catch a `\n`, and a line ends with one, so finding the lines you're looking for is easy

but I need a better understanding of the result to continue

Answer (score 0):

Since you added a Perl tag:

```
perl -pE 'BEGIN{
              $/ = "<key>servers</key>\n<dict>\n"; 
              $content = `cat file.xml`
          }
          $_.=$content' your_input_file
```